# Need help in creating persistence.xml..?

Tags: java, eclipse, jbpm, persistence.xml

I'm new to jbpm process. I'm using Eclipse to create jBPM process and to call it, For this we need persistance.xml it seems. I have no idea about it. Can somebody help me to create the persistance.xml file. How to create that file or if there is any-other way to call the jBPM process please share the code.
I'm stuck in this for more than 3 days.

jbPM6 I'm using...

Comment: create and put your persistence.xml under the META-INF folder.

Comment: What about the Contents inside of that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [this](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-test/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml) as an example. Make sure you update it for your database configuration.

Comment: To use this example in my project, what shall name shall i give for EntityManager Factory. Its JPAUNIT for me now. Im facing issue with that.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPAUNIT"). I dont know what that JPAUnit actually means to. Can u please explain more.?

Comment: You should use org.jbpm.persistence.jpa as that's defined here: https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-test/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml#L9